# How to import data from one sql server database to another using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, import

I have been developing application using VB.NET and SQL Server 2008. There is one software is already been developed and in running mode, now I have to develop facility that user can add one record on that software and same record will add into my database table also.

For that I have to write some code for when I will open particular screen / page in my application it will check the database table on that software and found if any new entry/record than it will appear in my application screen also.

In short I have to import record from database table from one database to another database using VB.NET code.

Please advice.

Anyone can please help me on this??